# ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list .when i orderd 2 columns getting this error

Tags: postgresql

```
 SELECT distinct pptr."task_run_id", pptr."task_run_name", pptr."created_by", 
             pptr."created_date", pptr."run_status", pptr."is_deleted", 
             ppca."pf_cus_account_id" ,ppca."pf_cus_account_name",
             ppcpd."customer_product_id", ppcpd."customer_product_name",pppt."pm_project_id"

 FROM project.pm_task_run pptr 
inner join project.pm_task_run_build_info trbi on trbi.task_run_id =pptr.task_run_id
inner join project.pm_project_tasks pppt on pptr."pm_project_task_id"=pppt."pm_project_task_id"  
inner join project.st_project_task psp on psp."project_task_id"=pppt."project_task_id"   
inner join project.pm_company_projects ppcpj on ppcpj."pm_project_id"=pppt."pm_project_id"           
inner join project.pm_customer_products ppcpd on ppcpd."customer_product_id"=ppcpj."customer_product_id" 
inner join project.pf_customer_account ppca on ppca."pf_cus_account_id"=ppcpd."pf_cus_account_id"       
where pptr.is_draft='false' and pptr.run_status IN ('Run', 'Pause','Scheduled','End' )
and pptr.start_date is not null

order by pptr.start_date,pptr.start_time desc
```

Comment: A `distinct` with so many columns rarely makes sense. And more often than not, it's used to remove duplicates caused by joins which is better done removing the join and replacing it with an EXISTS condition. Or maybe you are looking for `distinct on ()`

Comment: should i remove the distinct ?

Comment: how to handel the dublicates then?

Comment: pptr.start_date, pptr.start_time both columns are not in the select list you should try adding them in select.